# Print text between tags (inclusive) if certain text is found

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk, regular-expression, perl

I've got a task to extract data from several Apache servers.  The task is to print out:

```
<Directory ...>
  ...
</Directory>
```

where +ExecCGI is located within.  Let me give an example to illustrate.  Assume that the Apache configuration file has numerous Directory sections as indicated below:

```
<Directory /var/www/site1/htdocs>
  Options +ExecCGI
  ...
  ...
</Directory>
...
...
...
<Directory /var/www/site1/Promo>
  Options -ExecCGI
  ...
  ...
</Directory>
```

From above, I would only like to get the following output:

```
<Directory /var/www/site1/htdocs>
  Options +ExecCGI
  ...
  ...
</Directory>
```

I've searched the forums and have found posts where people have asked questions on how to print out a whole section between tags (I know how to do that), or to change certain text when found (again, I know how to do that).

I will be changing the +ExecCGI to -ExecCGI, but the changes need to go through a review process and hence this question so that I can pull this data out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
perl -l -0777 -ne 'for (m{<Directory.*?</Directory>}gs) {print if /\+ExecCGI/}'
```

Or with GNU `grep`:

```
grep -zPo '(?s)<Directory(?:.(?!</Directory))*?\+ExecCGI.*?</Directory>'
```

Comment: Excellent - just what I was looking for - brevity!

Comment: It would be better if you explain the grep or perl command little bit.

Comment: I use the perl variant of this answer so I'll comment only on that:

Comment: The -l means an octal value will follow the following -0 option.  In perlrun, it states that, and I quote, "Any value 0400 or above will cause Perl to slurp files whole, but by convention the value 0777 is the one normally used for this purpose." - taken from 'perldoc perlrun'

Comment: @AnthonyK, here there's no octal value after `-l` (otherwise that'd be `-l0777`). The only purpose is to set the output record separator to newline (`$\ = "\n"`). The next `-0777` sets the _input_ record separator (`$/ = undef` as 0777 is an invalid byte. That's know as the slurp mode). Basically `-l -0777` is equivalent to a `BEGIN{$\=$/="\n";$/=undef}`.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably also use `awk`

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="</Directory>\n"; ORS=RS} /\+ExecCGI/ {print}' file
```

Comment: That doesn't print the part starting at `<Directory` (you could use `index` and `substr` to extract the part that start at `<Directory`). Note that multi-character/regex RS are not portable (mawk and gawk only).

Answer (score 0):

If you can use `perl`, here is a solution:

```
$ perl -nle '
    if (/<Directory/) {
        $flag = 1;
    }
    push @a, $_ if $flag;
    if (/<\/Directory/) {
        $flag = 0;
        if (grep {$_ =~ /\+ExecCGI/} @a) {
            push @f, @a;
        }
        @a = ();
     }
END {
    print join "\n", @f;
}' file
<Directory /var/www/site1/htdocs>
  Options +ExecCGI
  ...
  ...
</Directory>
```

**Explanation**

- Each time we see `<Directory`, we set `$flag = 1`.
- If `$flag` is true (1 means true in boolean context), we push current entry to array `@a`.
- If we see `</Directory`, meaning we complete the block, we check if block contains `+ExecCGI` string `grep {$_ =~ /\+ExecCGI/`, then we push `@a` to `@f`.
- Set `@a` to empty array to process another block.

Comment: I like this solution for its elegance - not to mention that I also learnt some perl tidbits along the way.  Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Here's an example in Bash (You should be able to do something similar in pretty much any language):

```
$ cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash

DIR=0
BLOCK=''
while read line
do
    if [ $DIR -eq 0 ] ; then
        if [[ $(echo $line | grep -i '<Directory') ]] ; then
            DIR=1
            BLOCK="$line"
        fi
    else
        BLOCK="$BLOCK\n$line"
        if [[ $(echo $line | grep -i '</Directory') ]] ; then
            if [[ $(echo $BLOCK | grep -i 'Options.*+ExecCGI') ]] ; then
                echo -e $BLOCK
            fi
            DIR=0
            BLOCK=""
        fi
    fi
done
```

Basically, we're just saving the block as we go along and then `grepping` it to see if it's got our pattern in it.

It's very simple, and is likely to have problems with some edge cases (if your config file has \ in it it might confuse `echo -e` for example), but you could expand the basic idea to deal with them.

Example in use:

```
$ cat test.conf
<Directory /var/www/site1/htdocs>
  Options +ExecCGI
  1
  2
</Directory>
3
4
5
<Directory /var/www/site1/Promo>
  Options -ExecCGI
  6
  7
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/site1/htdocs>
  Options -Whatever +ExecCGI
  8
  9
</Directory>

$ cat test.conf | bash test.sh
<Directory /var/www/site1/htdocs>
Options +ExecCGI
1
2
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/site1/htdocs>
Options -Whatever +ExecCGI
8
9
</Directory>
```

Comment: Bash is my daily scripting language and I would have come up with something similar.  I was hoping to get something along a 1-liner but obviously I might be asking for too much.